# netcat is blocked, telnet gets connection

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I'm trying to install an svn server on my linux machine (ubuntu 9.04). I copied a line to start `svnserve` to the `inetd.conf` file and restarted `inetd`. But I'm not able to connect with an svn client to the server. I always get the error message

> connection refused

**Now comes the strange part:** If I call

```
netcat localhost 3690
```

the connection is refused, too. But if I call

```
telnet localhost 3690
```

I get some responses from `svnserve`.

**Any ideas what could be the cause of this - and how I can make my svnserver work?**

---

Some more details:

- I installed `inetutils-inetd` (Version 2:1.6-1)
- `netstat` gives me the line

  tcp6       0      0 :::3690                 :::*                    LISTEN
- If I disable all the "special IPv6 addresses" in `/etc/hosts`, `telnet` stops to work and gives me a "connection refused", too.
- I tried to activate the `daytime` service of `inetd` (port 13). Same behaviour: `netcat` isn't able to connect, `telnet` is.
- As far as I can see there is no firewall (`ufw` is installed but not enabled).

Answer (score 1):

Netcat only does IPv4, and the server is only listening on IPv6.

Try setting this kernel option, then killing and restarting `inetd`:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only=0
```

(And change the inetd service line to `tcp`. About time you start using v6)

Comment: `net.ipv6.bindv6only` is already 0. But I found a bug report, that inetutils-inetd only listens to ipv6 if not specified otherwise.

Comment: @tangens: I recommend switching to `xinetd`, it works well with both v4 and (if `flags = IPv6`) v6.

Comment: `xinetd` was installed by default, but I'm not familiar with its syntax, so I switched back to good old `inetd`. Perhaps I should give `xinetd` a try...

Comment: @tangens: xinetd does support the `inetd.conf` syntax and will read the file. Although I'm not sure how it interprets `tcp` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself...

The problem was this line in the `inetd.conf`:

```
svn stream tcp nowait subversion /usr/bin/svnserve svnserve -i -r /home/svn
```

After switching the keyword `tcp` to `tcp4` everything works fine. Now netstat gives me this output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3690            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```